# Converting this DFA to RE using the Brzozowski Algebraic Method

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

*Hello people, I'm trying to convert this DFA to RE using the Brzozowski Algebraic Method.*

*(DFA created with [JFlap](http://jflap.org/))*
[image: DFA to be converted to RE]

### My Attempt

#### Write down equations

> **R<sub>1</sub>** = b**R<sub>1</sub>** + a**R<sub>2</sub>** + ɛ
>
> **R<sub>2</sub>** = b**R<sub>2</sub>** + a**R<sub>3</sub>**
>
> **R<sub>3</sub>** = b**R<sub>2</sub>** + a**R<sub>1</sub>**

#### Eliminate equal R<sub>x</sub>'s from RHS

> **R<sub>1</sub>** = b*a**R<sub>2</sub>** + b*
>
> **R<sub>2</sub>** = b*a**R<sub>3</sub>**

#### New equations

> **R<sub>1</sub>** = b*a**R<sub>2</sub>** + b*
>
> **R<sub>2</sub>** = b*a**R<sub>3</sub>**
>
> **R<sub>3</sub>** = b**R<sub>2</sub>** + a**R<sub>1</sub>**

#### Substitute R<sub>2</sub> into R<sub>3</sub> and eliminate R<sub>3</sub> from RHS

> **R<sub>3</sub>** = bb*a**R<sub>3</sub>** + a**R<sub>1</sub>**
>
> **R<sub>3</sub>** = (bb*a)*a**R<sub>1</sub>**

#### Substitute R<sub>3</sub> into R<sub>2</sub>

> **R<sub>2</sub>** = b*a(bb*a)*a**R<sub>1</sub>**

#### New equations

> **R<sub>1</sub>** = b*a**R<sub>2</sub>** + b*
>
> **R<sub>2</sub>** = b*a(bb*a)*a**R<sub>1</sub>**
>
> **R<sub>3</sub>** = (bb*a)*a**R<sub>1</sub>**

#### Substitute R<sub>2</sub> into R<sub>1</sub> and eliminate R<sub>1</sub> from RHS

> **R<sub>1</sub>** = b*ab*a(bb*a)*a**R<sub>1</sub>** + b*
>
> **R<sub>1</sub>** = (b*ab*a(bb*a)*a)*b*

#### Answer

> **RE** = (b*ab*a(bb*a)*a)*b*

#### Issue(?)

> **The past exam paper answer is:** b*(ab*a(bb*a)*ab*)*
>
>
> **My calculated answer is:** (b*ab*a(bb*a)*a)*b*
>
>
> Are these 2 answers equal or have I done something wrong?

**EDIT:** The answer is correct even in the form I have provided; the textbook answer has gone a step forward having used the shifting rule to achieve its format.


*Here are some useful rules for simplifying RE's:*

- Shifting Rule: **E**(**FE**)* = (**EF**)***E**
- Denesting Rule: (**E*****F**)***E*** = (**E**+**F**)*

Comment: $x^*(yx^*)^*$ is the same thing as $(x^*y)^*x^*$ for any $x$ and $y$. However, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Is there a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thank you for your comments, I'll be sure to consider them in future posts. Perhaps I should have additionally asked whether any rules such as the shifting rule (I looked it up, must have missed it) you provided would be applicable in order to achieve the "textbook" answer I was given. That can be of help to any future readers having similar issues with their calculations.

Comment: This question is in the process of being closed, however there's a general question in here which would be fine to ask: How do you tell if two REs are equivalent?

Comment: As a rule, have confidence in the answer you got (until you prove yourself wrong), even if it is different from the one that is given to you. Our job is not to "get it right", our job is to prove ourselves right, **to ourselves**, and then to others.

Comment: @Pseudonym, that question is at least NP-hard. Doesn't make it an uninteresting question, just one hard to really give a satisfactory "answer" to.

Comment: @gsymeoni Your question: "whether any rules such as the shifting rule would be applicable in order to achieve the answer I was given" is a very interesting one, perhaps more suitable for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com. But first check whether it was not asked before (I didn't check myself) here or there.